# Move folders to other folders sorted by year

Tags: powershell

I have these files

```
Andromeda (2009)
Mrtik.2004.[director cut]
Jvengers 1999
```

To move and order folders by alphabetical order I can use

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path ??* |
  Move-Item -Destination { 
    # Determine the target dir - the input dir's first letter -
    # ensure that it exists, and output it.
    New-Item -Type Directory -Force (Join-Path $_.Parent.FullName $_.Name[0])
  }
```

this code create **A**, **J**, **M** folders and then moves them in this way

```
  A 
  | ---> Andromeda (2009)

  J
  | ---> Jvengers 1999
  
  M 
  | ---> Mrtik.2004.[director cut]
```

But I prefer another situation

```
1999
  | ---> Jvengers 1999
  
2004 
  | ---> Mrtik.2004.[director cut]

2009 
  | ---> Andromeda (2009)
```

any idea?

Comment: What if there is a file that doesn't have a year?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon If the file has no name it should not be moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it could be using `Group-Object` to group all folders by a matched pattern (a 4 number digit in this case - `\d{4}`) then you can iterate over the groups and in case needed create the destination folders and move the group of folders to it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Group-Object { [regex]::Match($_.Name, '\d{4}').Value } |
ForEach-Object {
    # if the pattern was not matched exclude this group
    # this is a folder without a year
    if(-not $_.Name) { return }

    $destination = Join-Path -Path $_.Group[0].Parent -ChildPath $_.Name
    if(-not (Test-Path $destination)) {
        $destination = New-Item $destination -ItemType Directory
    }
    
    # need to exclude those folders from the group that are our destination
    # without this you can trriger the following exception:
    # `Destination path cannot be a subdirectory of the source ...`
    $folders = $_.Group.Where{ $_.FullName -ne $destination }
    # if there are no folders to move, go to the next group
    if(-not $folders) { return }
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $folders -Destination $destination
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for folders works well : I try now to adapt your script to move files, and not folders, always into a year sorted directories but something I wrong. For example, I changed `Get-ChildItem -Directory` into `Get-ChildItem -File` but then files are not moved into year-sorted folders. I realized that my objects to be moved are files and not folders, sorry for my mistake

Comment: @Spring to get the parent folder of a file instead of `$_.Group[0].Parent` you would need to use `$_.Group[0].Directory` aside from that, _it should work with files_. I didn't test tho